# Conflicting scripts, Fancybox and a seamless audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using a seamless audio player called SCM Player (http://scmplayer.net/) and a JQuery plugin called FancyBox. There seems to be some issues with the two scripts clashing. When I add in the code from the player, fancybox stops working.

Here's what my code is looking like:
HEAD:

```
<!-- jquery lib -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fancybox -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.cart").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': false
    });

});
</script>
```

At the beginning of the BODY tag:

```
<!-- SCM Music Player http://scmplayer.net -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scmplayer.net/script.js" 
data-config="{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':false,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'placement':'top','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'Tommy Castro - Bad Case of Love','url':'http://santacruzbluesfestival.com/sounds/saturday/01.mp3'},{'title':'Tommy Castro - Exception to the Rule','url':'http://santacruzbluesfestival.com/sounds/saturday/02.mp3'}]}" ></script>
<!-- SCM Music Player script end -->
```

Here's the problem in action:
http://santacruzbluesfestival.com/dev/buy-tickets.php

The fancybox popup should be happening when you click on the "ADD TO CART" button.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or the link to your site so we could see ?

Comment: Here's the problem in action: http://santacruzbluesfestival.com/dev/buy-tickets.php

The fancybox popup should be happening when you click on the "ADD TO CART" button.

Comment: I think SCM Player recreate your html into an iframe, so the event binding for fancybox are lost, I don't know if there is events for SMC player, but the trick would be to bind fancybox after smc player.

Comment: Maybe if you add $("a.cart").fancybox({..]); in the body of the document, it will work

Comment: I actually had it that way originally and it wasn't working, so I moved all the JS into the header for cleanliness... I also noticed the smc player was throwing the whole site into an iframe. Maybe a different audio player would be better.

Comment: Maybe, even if your fancybox would work, it cannot be displayed outside the IFrame it's into..

Comment: That sounds like the issue to me. Might try to look for a new player. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use scm's code in FancyBox page. Just add in default.aspx is enough for work for all pages!